# Unexpected Subview after adding UIViewContainer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I had a single ViewController, where I had a Table View which loaded data from  a struct and all was well.   I added a segmented controller and then created 2 UIViewContainers.

I moved all of my Tableview code to UIViewContainer 1 and UIViewContainer 2 is currently empty.  I also moved the TableView in the storyboard to the new UIViewContainer 1

in the code velow UIViewcontainer 1 = tableContainer
UIViewController 2 = mapContainer

I have added the code for the segmented view controller as such:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableContainer: UIView!


@IBAction func showContainer(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tableContainer.alpha = 1
            self.mapContainer.alpha = 0
        })

    }else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.tableContainer.alpha = 0
            self.mapContainer.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}
```

This is more or less the only code in my main View Controller.

When I run, the compile works fine but crashes at load with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There are unexpected 
subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already 
fired once or a subview was added programmatically?'
***
```

Have I missed something that I need to do to the tableView or views in general?

Comment: This sounds to me like a view was added in the wrong manner. I might be missing something, but this isn't enough information for me to solve this bug. Are you adding a view controller into another view controller programmatically?

Comment: I used storyboard to add 2 container views.  I have created 2 files of type UIViewController, to link to these containers, is this where I have gone wrong?  

When using segmented controller with Containers, do I need to create seperate files to put my code for each view?

Comment: I don't fully understand your setup, but adding a UIViewController into another UIViewController is easily doable. You just have to follow certain guidelines.

Comment: @JadeReynolds Your setup is little messy. I guess you have not imported your whole code properly. If tableview is in storyboard, have you not created its IBOutlet?

Answer (score 0):

The log says that there are unexpected subviews in the container view. You might want to make sure that all the subviews are moved to the (embed)segueD UIViewController and not in the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this now.  Something must have gone wrong when setting up, I removed all Containers and put the app back to how it was, started again and it is working ok now

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I accidentally executed `segue.perform()` in `prepare(for:sender:)`. Once I removed that line, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, here is the solution. Given your container view is called `containerView`, call

```
containerView.removeSubviews()
```

before you call

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueID", sender: self)
```